# Linq How to Group By

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a query like below. I want to group my values by "RapId"

Result must be come like this:

RaporId 1, List of UserId  15,24,23
RaporId 2, List of UserId  18,45,57

```
var sorgu = (from ra in Model1
                     join me  in Model2
                     on ra.RapId equals me.RapId 
                     select new
                     {
                         RapId = ra.RapId,
                         UserId= ra.RaportorId,

                     })
                     .GroupBy(x=>x.RapId )

                      .SelectMany(x => x)
                     .ToList();


           var results = sorgu.GroupBy(p => p.RapId , p => p.UserId,
                     (key, g) => new { RapId = key, UserId= g.ToList() });
```

I get an error like this

```
 > Error 39 Cannot convert lambda expression to type
 > 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<AnonymousType#1>'
 > because it is not a delegate type
```

What's wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler thinks you are trying to use [`this` overload:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549272(v=vs.100).aspx) But you are passing a lambda expressions instead of `IEqualityComparer`.I think you just need to remove `p => p.UserId` :

```
var results = sorgu.GroupBy(p => p.RapId,
                 (key, g) => new { RapId = key, UserId= g.ToList() });
```

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks a lot.